# Installing tig and ncurses without root privileges

Tags: software-installation, ncurses

I don't have root privileges on our servers but I would like to install `tig`. Downloading the source and running

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/pkg
```

gives me

```
configure: error: ncurses not found
```

Okay, `ncurses-devel` isn't installed either. Installing `ncurses` works fine. But how do I tell the `./configure` script now that `ncurses` is installed in my `$HOME` directory? Usually this works fine with something like

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$HOME/pkg/include ./configure --prefix=$HOME/pkg
C_INCLUDE_PATH=$HOME/pkg/include/ncurses make
```

but for `tig`, this doesn't work, `./configure` still throws the same error. How can I tell `tig` where to find `ncurses`?

Of course I can just skip this part in the `./configure` step, but I then get these errors when making `git`:

```
/home/foo/pkg/include/ncurses/curses.h: In function ‘NCURSES_EXPORT_VAR’:
/home/foo/pkg/include/ncurses/curses.h:274: error: expected declaration specifiers before ‘acs_map’
```

Comment: why not just ask your system admin(s) to install `tig` for you?  it's their job.  `tig` is extremely unlikely to cause problems or conflicts  with other programs on the system, so there's no really good reason for them to refuse.  If company policy doesn't allow random software from the internet to be installed, you shouldn't be trying to get around that by installing in your home dir.  Try to get the policy changed or an exception made for `tig` instead.

Comment: I agree. But `tig` in the repositories is very old. Still, the administrator could install `ncurses-devel`, and then I could easily install `tig`. However, these are governmental servers and the bureaucratic overhead is huge. This always reminds me of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GI5kwSap9Ug so I prefer to struggle on the technical side, rather than not finding the form A38.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would do that by

```
./configure CFLAGS="-I$HOME/pkg/include" LIBS="-L$HOME/pkg/lib"
```

as you might see by running

```
./configure --help
```

(assuming that you installed ncurses in `$HOME/pkg`, as your question implies).

Comment: Then I get `checking for C compiler default output file name...
configure: error: in '/home/foo/pkg/install/tig':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See 'config.log' for more details.`. I assume `CFLAGS` needs compiler flags, not path's?

Comment: sorry (long day).

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much! I should have learned this makefile language a long time ago!

Comment: It's useful: you can reuse that little bit many times.

Comment: This is extremely useful for many other things.  Of course, `--help` lists all those options, but then it is not so clear how to actually use them.